# Randomly select 3 of 9 from json file with jquery

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, select

I have 1 json file :

```
{"unit":[{
    "a": "word1",
    "b": "audio1",
    "c": "img1"
  },
  {
     "a": "word11",
    "b": "audio11",
    "c": "img11"
  },
  {
     "a": "word101",
    "b": "audio101",
    "c": "img101"
  },
  {
    "a": "word2",
    "b": "audio2",
    "c": "img2"
  },
  {
     "a": "word12",
    "b": "audio12",
    "c": "img12"
  },
  {
     "a": "word102",
    "b": "audio102",
    "c": "img102"
  },
  {
    "a": "word3",
    "b": "audio3",
    "c": "img3"
  },
  {
     "a": "word13",
    "b": "audio13",
    "c": "img13"
  },
  {
     "a": "word103",
    "b": "audio103",
    "c": "img103"
  }
]}
```

I want select random 3 in 9 object and save in array ex:
a:('word102','word3','word1') ...

Help me!

Comment: have a look at `Math.random()`

Comment: you can use for...loop to loop 3 time.

Answer (score 1):

I just assumed `xObj` is holding your `JSON`.

Try,

```
 var xArray = xObj["unit"];
 var xArrayLength = xArray.length;
 var xRandomValue = xArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * xArrayLength)];
```

Comment: Thanks. I 've got the data and pushed it in the array :   
for (var i=0;i<datajson.unit.length;i++)
{num++; 
items.push(datajson.bai[i]); }
Your can help me!

Comment: @user3349557 Glad to help.! consider this answer as accepted if you wish.!

Comment: @user3349557 Have you got the expected result.?